# use air native extension to show a simple native button?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, air, air-native-extension

I'm mainly an AS3 coder and I know Java fair enough to be able to build my own ANE files for Vibration, Toast, dialogs and that simple stuff...

using air native extensions are cool but I'm getting a bit disappointed not being able to create a simple button with it.

I know creating a simple native button is a silly thing to do as it is very easy to create buttons in air directly but I'm using it as an example.

So the question is that is it possible to create .ane for calling native Button in android? at all?

it seems like I can't create any .ane files rather than abstract tools like push notifications or popup like windows like progress bars and dialog boxes.

is it right to say that a simple native button cannot be created with air native extensions?

Comment: What do you want to do with your native button? From your question, it seems that you know you can do graphical stuff with native extensions (as per http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/nativealert/) so I don't understand the distinction. Of course you can have an extension that shows a button. But you do realise you'll have to handle all the interaction with AIR as you would any other native extension, right? You won't be able to add it to the display list, etc...

Comment: I did some more readings and found this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html (scroll down to Limitations) where it says: Extensions cannot directly integrate interactive objects, such as native UI controls, with the display list. (Other items, such as native dialog boxes, may work, depending on the platform.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who wondering why a simple button cannot be called with extensions, read http://adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html (scroll down to Limitations) where it says: Extensions cannot directly integrate interactive objects, such as native UI controls, with the display list. (Other items, such as native dialog boxes, may work, depending on the platform.)